# rails: how to have an image for the submit tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been using submit tag helpers.

```
<%= submit_tag 'Submit' %>
```

I have an image called my_image.png.

How can I make the submit button be an image?

I tried:

```
    <%= submit_tag '#{image_tag("Login_small.png", :width=>70)}' %>
```

But that doesn't work..

Comment: In any case, you can't do `'#{foo}'` -- there's no interpolation in strings using single quotes. You have to use double quotes: `"#{foo}"`

Comment: I've answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201361/adding-a-submit-button-image-to-a-rails-form  how to use link instead of submit button using JS.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Check out [image_submit_tag](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-image_submit_tag), it is what you are looking for.  It is used like   `image_submit_tag("login.png")`

Answer (score 3):

I believe you'd like to use `image_submit_tag`.

[See the docs for more details.](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-image_submit_tag)