# Adding a submit button image to a Rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm creating a form in Rails for submitting comments, and I want the submit button to be an image, rather than an HTML button.  In [this bit of documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-image_submit_tag), it says the code is `image_submit_tag`, but I can't get it to work in my code.

Here's what I'm working with:

```
<% form_for [@post, Comment.new], :remote => true do |f| %>
<p>
    <%= f.label :body, "Add a comment" %><br />
    Name <%= f.text_field :name %><br />
    Website<%= f.text_field :website %><br />
    Twitter<%= f.text_field :twitter %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
</p>
<div id="comment-form">

    <div id="comment-button"><p>
        <%= f.image_submit_tag("comment-button.png") %></p>
        </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What happens?  Is there an error message you  can post?

Comment: I get `undefined method 'image_submit_tag' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0xb6cdde88>` in Rails 3.0.3. Is this a new form builder helper (the docs for v3.0.5 list it as one...)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it like so:

ERB:

```
<%= f.submit "" %>
```

CSS:

```
input[type="submit"]
{
  background:url(mybutton.png);
}
```

Comment: Right you are!  Took a little CSS styling, but now it looks right, thanks.

Comment: It's easy to make this accessible to everyone, see thomasfedb's answer.

Answer (score 53):

I just fell over this one, trying to solve the same problem.
A sudden thought made me just try something like this:

```
<%= f.submit "Comment", :type => :image, :src => "/images/comment-button.png" %>
```

Will create something like this:

```
<input id="comment_submit" name="commit" src="/images/comment-button.png" type="image" value="Comment" />
```

Try it out :-)

Comment: Awesome, thanks. The css way is no good in my case because I have db-driven images for the "submit" button.

Comment: Note for rails >=3.1 you'll want to use a helper because of the asset pipeline:  :src => image_path("submit.png")

Comment: This answer is spot-on. No messing around with CSS, just pure awesome rails code. Would have been good as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 13):

I believe the 'tag' methods cannot be called on the form builder object.

By 'tag' methods I mean things from the ActionView::Helpers::FormTagHelper module.

It should work if you do:

```
<div id="comment-button"><p>
  <%= image_submit_tag("comment-button.png") %></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

Yup, the following should work:

```
  <%= image_submit_tag("comment-button.png") %></p>
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/image_submit_tag

Answer (score 4):

Working from Zabba's example a more accessible solution would be:

View:

```
<%= f.submit "Submit" %>
```

CSS:

```
input[type="submit"]
{
  background:url(mybutton.png);
  text-indent: -9999em;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please using delete on line:

```
<%= f.image_submit_tag("/assets/icon-search.png") %>
```

change into:

```
<%= image_submit_tag("/assets/icon-search.png") %>
```

more details on `image_submit_tag`

Answer (score 1):

For rails 3.1 and above

```
<%= f.submit "Submit", :type => :image, :src => image_path("submit.png") %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following JS trick.

1) In your application.js:

```
function submitFormWithoutButton(formId) {
  document.getElementById(formId).submit(); 
}
```

2) Then in your form replace `f.submit` line(s) with:

```
<%= link_to "#", onclick: "submitFormWithoutButton('ID_OF_YOUR_FORM')" do %>
  <%=  image_tag("PATH_TO_YOUR_AWESOME_ICON") %>
<% end %>
```

3) It takes only to replace uppercase placeholders with your form's id and path to the image file you want to use as a button.

Now you can submit your forms through nice and obedient links instead of stubborn and tricky buttons!

***Don't forget to vote up if that helps!***