# post form submitting a get request header

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms

I am developing a personal website in ruby on rails.
I have a form being dynamically generated as such:

```
<div>
  <%= @request_type %>
  <h1>Login Form</h1>
  <% if @error == true %>
    <h1>Error: Login Information Invalid</h1>
  <% end %>
  <%= form_for :user, url: {action: "login"}, method: :post do |f| %>
    <p> E-mail: <br /> <%= f.text_field :email %></p>
    <p> Password: <br /> <%= f.password_field :password %></p>
    <p><%= submit_tag "Log In!", :disable_with => "Logging in..." %></p>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

The `@request_type` is being set as `request.request_method()`, for debugging purposes for now.

The HTML generated for the form specifically looks like the following:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/login" method="post">
  <!-- authentication token here -->
  <p> E-mail: <br /> <input id="user_email" name="user[email]" type="text" /></p>
  <p> Password: <br /> <input id="user_password" name="user[password]" type="password" /></p> 
  <p><input data-disable-with="Logging in..." name="commit" type="submit" value="Log In!" /></p>
</form>
```

However, any time I submit it, the headers are set with the GET method, instead of POST as declared in the form element (see `method="post"`).

The R.O.R. might have nothing to do with what's going on...  I am using Chrome to test my application.  Any thoughts about why this is happening?  I absolutely need the request to use POST.

If there's any other information that might be useful to solving this, please ask, and I will provide it.

Edit: Relevant routes:

```
login POST /login(.:format)         user#login
      GET  /login(.:format)         user#login'
```

I see no reason to post routes that are not associated with the "login" action.

Comment: Can you do a rake routes and post the output ?

Comment: @CaffeineCoder I've posted the relevant routes... I'm assuming this is what you're looking for?  I can post ALL of them if you REALLY want...

Comment: Nope , this is ok . I think the answer below shows what exactly is wrong with the code .

Comment: What are the post parameters after submitting the form ? post  a snippet from console

Comment: @Debadatt It's sending a GET request somehow; no POST parameters are being.. well, posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

and `= submit_tag` should be `= f.submit_tag`

Also replace:

```
<%= form_for :user, url: {action: "login"}, method: :post do |f| %>
```

With:

```
<%= form_for :user, url: login_path, method: :post do |f| %>
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "place the url in a cleaner way."?  Or, I'm guessing you just now did that in your edit.
Also, thanks for the note about the submit tag.

Comment: Sorry I wrote that before you add the routes. I posted `login_path` suggestion.

Comment: I tried f.submit_tag, and it gave me an error `undefined method 'image_submit_tag' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:somethingsomething>`... a quick search told me to use `f.submit`, but I'm still having no luck with getting it to use POST ( source http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201361/adding-a-submit-button-image-to-a-rails-form )

Comment: Hey, I figured out the problem... and it was a dumb one.
The problem is malformed HTML from a containing view, that wasn't being reported...  I had a form tag that wasn't closed (I had `<form> .... <form>` instead of `<form> ... </form>`).  And apparently that wasn't import enough for my browser or ruby to warn me.  Time to set up stricter internet options...

Comment: I suggest that you use haml. It does't have such issues, its based on indentation